# Extending np.polyfit to 3 dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have a pandas df and I need to create a continuous mapping of the indices to values. If df[x, y] = z, I need to be able to find a function f(x, y) that can calculate z for values of x and y not in the indices of the dataframe. I've been using np.polyfit and np.poly1d but that only works on individual rows and columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
coefs = np.polyfit(df[sample_row], df.index, 10)
func = np.poly1d(coefs)
```

I wrote the following code to turn the dataframe into X, Y, and Z numpy arrays, but I need to find f: f(x, y) = z

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(df.columns, df.index)
X = X.flatten()
Y = Y.flatten()
Z = df.to_numpy().flatten()
```

Comment: [featuretools](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/install.html) can help you generate the polynomial features.

Comment: If you believe there is a polynomial relationship between your x,y, and z, then perhaps [`sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) may suffice to generated your desired features.  The output of `PolynomialFeatures` may then be used in any of several regressors (such as [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)).